# How to handle(cy.get()) dynamic element if exist do A if not do B

Tags: cypress

I have to handle dialog element, if element present do something and not do other, but cy.get('...') CypressError: Timed out retrying, cause sometimes element not present. How to handle it

I tried cy.get('...').find('...'), cy.get('...').then() and cy.get('...').should('to.exist') it doesn't work.

```
cy.get('div.ui-dialog-content.ui-widget-content > p-messages > div > ul > li:nth-child(2) > span')
        .should('to.exist').then(() => {
            // only do if found element 
            cy.get('div.ui-dialog-titlebar.ui-widget-header.ui-helper-clearfix > a > span')
                .click()
        })

// do another
```

Expect: if dialog show up close it and continue test, if dialog doesn't show just test normally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cypress docs have a guide about conditional testing, with an [example of how to run your tests based off element existence](https://on.cypress.io/conditional-testing#Element-existence).

I've rewritten the code in your question to use the way the example from the docs does it. This should work:

```js
cy.get('body').then(($body) => {
  if ($body.find('div.ui-dialog-content.ui-widget-content > p-messages > div > ul > li:nth-child(2) > span').length) {
    // element found, do something here...
    cy.get('div.ui-dialog-titlebar.ui-widget-header.ui-helper-clearfix > a > span')
      .click()
  } else {
    // do something else...
  }
})
```